# Angular 6 - wrong property instanceof from example

Tags: angular, instanceof

I got this code from Angular example

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };

  constructor() { 
    console.log(this.hero instanceof Hero);
    console.log(this.hero instanceof Object);

    const otherHero = new Hero();
    console.log(otherHero);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The console output is:

```
false
true
true
```

If property hero is defined as Hero type then why **instanceof** give me false ?
What is the sense to declare this property as Hero type if after seting value it is not Hero type but normal Object type

Comment: You aren't taking it's instance, you are just declaring a type!

Comment: I know what happend but I just thought TypeScript will change this type.
For me this Angular exmple is misleading if you are begginer.

Answer (score 2):

```
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
```

In the above code you are only declaring a Type of the hero property as `Hero`, but you are assigning an Object literal. It should be `hero: Hero = new Hero()`, then only the `this.hero instanceOf Hero` property will return `true`.

**Explanation:**

JavaScript is a prototype based language. The base class for all the other classes including String, Array is `Object`. So, In your case you are creating an Object using object literal `{}`. Typescript doesn't show any error because `Hero` class also extends from `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Hero extends from object, for this reason it lets you assign a JSON (**JavaScript Object Notation**)

It is simply an example, the normal way of working will be with objects of the specific type.
If you want a variable of Hero type, you have to declare it implicitly using constructor new Hero()